# Memcached disable on test environment?

Tags: memcached

For example I have on a dedicated server a live site and in a sub folder a test site?

Is there a way to disable memcached on test site because I don't want that thing I make on test site to affect memory cache on live site.

Comment: Are your test site and live site share same memcached instance and have same keys.

Comment: yes... they use the same memory that is the problem.... even I add a namespace in front of each key it will take from my server memory

Comment: we need more info.  what are you using as a client to access memcached?  The server is not going to be aware of which site is connecting to it, you will need to change something on the client side.

Answer (score 2):

In your environments/test.rb, 
add this line **config.cache_store = :null_store** in order to disable the caching.